# Create table using CSV header in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I want to create a table using CSV file header when I upload a file.

If table does not exists then create table using CSV header
else just import data into a specified table.

This is my file upload code.

```
    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
    $this->validate($request, ['file' => 'mimes:txt,xls,tsv,xlsx' ]);
        //Get original file name
        $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

        //Get original file extention
        $fileExtention = $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //get upload user id
        $uploadedUserId = Auth::user()->id;

        //get file upload timestamp in microseconds
        $microseconds = microtime(true);

        //remove special characters from file name
        $sansSpecial = preg_replace('/[\'\"\,\(\)\s]/', '_',$filename);

        //prepend timestamp to modified file name
        $prependTimestamp = $microseconds.'-'.$sansSpecial;

        //create unique hash code from modified file name
        $uniqueFileHash = Hash::make($prependTimestamp);



        $uploadDirectory ='/app/public';
        $uploadPath = storage_path().$uploadDirectory;

         if(Storage::exists('./public/'.$filename))
        {
            Use the path info helper function to get file info.
            $fileInfo= pathinfo($filename);

            //Add timestamp to file if file already exist.
            $finsert = $fileInfo['filename'].date('(m-d-y h i s)').'.'.$fileExtention;

            //Store file into directory.
            $insert = $request->file->storeAs('./public/',$finsert);

            //New upload object.        
            $file = new Upload;

            //Assign new file name
            $file->file_name = $finsert;

            //Assign new modiefied file name with prepended timestamp
            $file->modified_file_name = $prependTimestamp;

            //Assign unique file hash.
            $file->unique_file_hash = $uniqueFileHash;

            //Assign full file path
            $file->file_full_path = $uploadPath;

            //Assign uploaded user id
            $file->uploaded_user_id = $uploadedUserId;

            //Store all informamation into database.
            $file->save();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: I have updated a question with the code of file upload.

Comment: So what are the contents of the `save()` method on `Upload` and what does not work?

Comment: This line    $insert = $request->file->storeAs('./public/',$finsert);
will store file into directory and   $file->save();   will store information of file into database.  So during upload I want to create table from the header and store data into that table.